# Swift Mapkit remove annotations and release memory

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I am using mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations) to remove annotations but I can see from debug in Xcode that the memory for each annotation is not released and this eventually causes my app to crash. Is there a way to release it? I have looked at ARC and deinit and weak but I can't see how this relates to my code.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class StationMarkerView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        
      guard let station = newValue as? Station else {
        return
      }
      canShowCallout = true

        let mapsButton = FavouriteButton()
        let  bool = station.is_favourite
        let image = bool! ? "star.fill": "star"
        
        mapsButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: image), for: .normal)
        
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = mapsButton
        
      markerTintColor = station.markerTintColor
      glyphImage = station.glyphImage
      
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried using weak for "mapButton" but Xcode gives me a dealocation warning.

Thanks any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the annotation inside `StationMarkerView `? Show the code for mapButton touch too

Comment: no, annotations are remove when a refresh button is pressed. I'll edit for the mapButton code thanks - ok so I can't edit posts yet :(

Comment: If you have any callback/delegate, then mark them with weak, if you pass anything that can cause retain cycle, then try without them first

Comment: How do you mean try without them first? I did mark the only delegate that I use as weak thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick and dirty solution to my problem. Removing the annotations and then changing the maptype seems to release all memory relating to the mapView.

So to refresh my map I do ...

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        
velibManager.fetchVelib()
        
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
```